# Calculate $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 169$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Calculate $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 169$

By hand I checked that 
$x^2 \equiv -1 \mod 13$ gives these solutions:
$$ x \equiv 5  \mbox{ or } x \equiv 8 \mod 13 $$
Let say that I take $x \equiv 5 \mod 13$ so I have
$$ x\equiv 13k+5 \mod 169 \mbox { for some } k $$
so I calculating again by `lifting` ( I found this term there [Solve $99x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 125$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3221171/677339) )

$$(13k+5)^2 \equiv -1 \mod 169$$
$$169k^2 + 130k + 25 \equiv 168 \mod 169$$
$$130k \equiv 143 \mod 169$$
$$ k \equiv \frac{143}{130} \mod 169$$
but my $k$ doesn't seem to be integer... Wolfram tells that the solutions are
$$x \equiv 70 \mod 169 \mbox{ and }x \equiv 99 \mod 169 $$

Comment: I think you meant $169k^\color{red}2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:
$\mod 169:$
$$k \equiv \frac{143}{130} \equiv \frac{-26}{-39} \equiv \frac{2}{3} \equiv \frac{112}{168} \equiv \frac{112}{-1} \equiv -112 \equiv 169 - 112 \equiv 57 $$
so your $x$ is
$$x \equiv 57 \cdot 13 + 5 \equiv 746 \equiv 70  $$
so $$ x = 70 + 169n $$ as you wrote. The same thing can be done for other solution.

Answer (score 3):

From $130k\equiv 143$ mod $169$, you actually get $10k\equiv 11$ mod 13.

Then, $k\equiv 10^{-1}\cdot 11$ and you can find $10^{-1}(mod\,13)$ by Euclidean algorithm on finding $x,y$ s.t. $10x+13y=1$. Actually, we have $10\cdot 4-13\cdot 3=1$. Thus, $10^{-1}\equiv 4$ mod $13$.

Now, $k\equiv 44\equiv 5$ mod 13.

Put this $k$ in your work and everything will go well now

Comment: P.S. In some sense, what you call 'lifting' is closely related to Hensel lemma.

Comment: Can you a bit more explain how you got $10k \equiv 11 \mod 13$? It is not obvious for me

Comment: @Tester1998 Cancelling $\,13\,$ shows $\,130k = 143+169n\iff 10k = 11 + 13n\ \ $

Comment: Generally $ab \equiv ac \pmod n \Longleftrightarrow b \equiv c \pmod {n'}$, where $n'=\frac{n}{\gcd(a,n)}$, which can be proven directly using the definition of congruences. In your case, we have $a=13, b=10k, c=11, n=169, n'=13$.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track.

You could have said

$$169k^\color{red}2 + 130k + 25 \equiv -1 \mod 169$$

$$130k \equiv -26 \mod 169$$

$$10k \equiv -2 \mod 13$$

$$5k \equiv -1 \mod 13$$

$$k \equiv 5 \mod 13$$